# How can I record a partial refund for a membership?

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, contributions, refund

A user has just renewed their membership, and inadvertently opted for the default amount (60) rather than the correct amount for their particular situation (30). The contribution page offers two price options.

We've actioned the partial refund to address the overpayment, but I need to make a record in CiviCRM of this partial refund.

Right now it looks like the simplest option is to create a new manual contribution record with a negative value, assuming that's do-able, but it's far from ideal. Is there a better way that enables me to keep the membership and the record of the credit card payment already made?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can create refund of overpayment transaction using edit line item extension

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that out.

Comment: are we talking https://civicrm.org/extensions/line-item-editor - if so would be good to have the link in the Answer - just 'line item editor' not exact match with 'edit line item' and there is every chance there is more than one such extension around :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not use the 'Record refund' link on the contribution page? This keeps the history nice and tidy.